# Aparecer duas casas decimais

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Nesse código que tenho, quando valor chega 200.00... ele mostra 200, quando tem casas decimais, ele mostra as casa decimais... 200.55 = 200.55

Porém, preciso que ele mostre as duas casas decimais mesmo que seja "10.00", "00" depois do ponto...

outra coisa é que preciso que apareça "," de vez de ponto no print do site

Pensei em colocar, mas não sei onde colocaria...

```
            total = parseFloat(total.toFixed(2));
```

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('select[name="service[]"]').change(function() {

        let selects = jQuery("select[name=\"service[]\"]");
        let total = 0;
        
        /* Percorre todos os select */
        $(selects).map(function(i, e) {
          let values = $(e).find(":selected");

       
          /* Percorre todos os valores selecionados */
          $(values).map(function(k, j) {
            total += parseFloat( $(j).data('price').replace(",", ".") );
          });
        });

        $("#preview_value").text(total);

    });
});
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver a questão https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/297362/8063 que vc abandonou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
 var total = 200;
 console.log(total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
```

Edit. Adicionei um exemplo para melhor ilustrar.

```js
$('#numero').keyup(function(){
    $('#conversao').text(parseFloat($('#numero').val()).toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="numero"/>

<p id="conversao"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Convertendo um inteiro para 2 casas decimais.

```
<script>
var x = '146870';

    function format(num){
        return (num / 100).toFixed(2);
    }

    alert(format(x));
</script>
```

Saida será 1468.70